# How do you place a cut at a specific measurement?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, measurement

I am learning Blender and come across this instance often yet still can't figure out how to solve it. If I have a wall and I want to cut a hole out using boolean difference, how do I place the object to do the cutting at a specific measurement from the edge of the wall? Say for example, .880m from the edge. (I have my units set to metric)

[image]

Comment: You can place the door along the edge and move it the distance you want.

Comment: Ok thank you! Though I am going to clarify what you said a bit more for anyone else who may come across this problem as it took me a couple of minutes and a bit of fiddling around to realise what you meant (I thought you meant the edge I was on. Doh). Snapping my door to the LEFT hand edge (the short edge that runs along the x-axis in the photo) and pressing enter then allowed me to move the door object back again on the y-axis but now I can enter the numerical value/see the correct value in the top left because I am moving from the right place of origin.

Comment: .. and if your measurements are repetitive, you can think like a carpenter, and keep your own collection of home-made measuring-rods and wedges, which exist only to snap, and be snapped to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use snap to attach the face to the wall edge:

[image]

[image]

Then use typing move to manage your door to the desired position:

[image]